# Decoding base64 string? please :(

Tags: php, base64

```
<?php $OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$O00O00O00=__LINE__;$OO00O0000=1132;eval((base64_decode('JE8wMDBPME8wMD1mb3BlbigkT09PME8wTzAwLCdyYicpO3doaWxlKC0tJE8wME8wME8wMClmZ2V0cygkTzAwME8wTzAwLDEwMjQpO2ZnZXRzKCRPMDAwTzBPMDAsNDA5Nik7JE9PMDBPMDBPMD0oYmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZShzdHJ0cihmcmVhZCgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDM3MiksJ0VudGVyeW91d2toUkhZS05XT1VUQWFCYkNjRGRGZkdnSWlKakxsTW1QcFFxU3NWdlh4WnowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ky89JywnQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVphYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ejAxMjM0NTY3ODkrLycpKSk7ZXZhbCgkT08wME8wME8wKTs=')));return;?>

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
```

I can't seem to decode this base64 string which is in the footer of a wordpress theme. I want to be able to add more to the footer.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks more like something malicious.

Comment: Did you try to decode it with a online tool like: https://www.base64decode.org/ Whats in the seccond line? Is that the base64 Code you want to add? Whats the HTML Code around that PHP Block? Do you really Need to decode that Block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is the decoded piece of code with readable variables (for educational purposes):

```
<?php
    $the_current_file = __FILE__;
    $the_line_number_of_this_line   = __LINE__;

    $fileResource = fopen($the_current_file, 'rb');

    while (--$the_line_number_of_this_line) //For every line of code the code before this line
    {
        fgets($fileResource, 1024); //
    }

    fgets($fileResource, 4096);

    $codeToEvaluate = (base64_decode(strtr(fread($fileResource, 372), 'EnteryouwkhRHYKNWOUTAaBbCcDdFfGgIiJjLlMmPpQqSsVvXxZz0123456789+/=', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/')));
    eval($codeToEvaluate);

    return;
```

So basically, whereever this piece of code is included, it takes every line before it and replaces the characters `EnteryouwkhRHYKNWOUTAaBbCcDdFfGgIiJjLlMmPpQqSsVvXxZz0123456789+/=` with `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/`. Then, it base64 decodes that and eval's it. I'd do a `die($codeToEvaluate);` before `eval($codeToEvaluate)` to find out what piece of code is executed.

**But then, seriously.** If the developers of this theme tried to obfuscate something from you, either it's malicious or you're trying to crack past some licensing because you don't want their attribution in the footer. Credit them or pay them.

So bottom line: *Buy the goddamn theme or find another*.

**EDIT**

This seems to be the code, thats being executed:

```
 $purchasecode = PURCHASE_CODE;
    $target_url   = "http://www.jobzeek.com/api/search/?jobzeek=$jobzeek&indeed=$indeed&careerjet=$careerjet&purchasecode=$purchasecode&keyword=$q&location=$l&co=$co&sort=$sort&radius=$radius&st=$st&jtype=$jt&start=$start&old=$fromage";
//echo $target_url;
    $userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';

// make the cURL request to $target_url
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);
    $xmlstring = curl_exec($ch);

    $xmlstring  = $xmlstring;
    $json_reply = json_decode($xmlstring, true);
```

Comment: There parse this file xml content codes . I purchased the software but can not develop

Comment: Take a look at my edited post. This seems to impersonate a Googlebot to connect to Jobzeek.com, which seems a bit suspicious to me (although I don't know what you do).

Comment: jobzek skin attracts job

Answer (score 0):

Nice try, your base64 look like this:

```
$O000O0O00=fopen($OOO0O0O00,'rb');
while(--$O00O00O00)
 fgets($O000O0O00,1024);
fgets($O000O0O00,4096);
$OO00O00O0(base64_decode(strtr(fread($O000O0O00,372),'EnteryouwkhRHYKNWOUTAaBbCcDdFfGgIiJjLlMmPpQqSsVvXxZz0123456789+/=','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/')));
eval($OO00O00O0);%
```

Ahm.... yeah, i'm not gonna execute eval on that.